# Asp.Net Core RC2 with Microsoft.Owin

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, owin, coreclr

Could not compile project while adding `using Microsoft.Owin;` line at `Startup.cs`. VS throws an error:
`ASP.NET Core 5.0 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Owin' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`
Here is my `project.json` file:

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.Owin": "3.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Owin.Security": "3.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth": "3.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies": "3.0.1"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnetcore50": {}
    },
    "bundleExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

Am I missing something?

Prerequisites: Visual Studio 2015 CTP version 14.0.22609.0 D14REL, Empty ASP.NET 5 Preview template

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the Owin libraries (version 3.0.1) are not compatible with Microsoft's new Core version of the .NET framework.

To fix this you can change your frameworks entry from `aspnetcore50` to `aspnet50` which runs your application using the full .NET framework rather than the core version.

I've just started exploring ASP 5 as well and have found the examples here useful: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/tree/dev/samples/1.0.0-beta4/HelloMvc

Edit: Now that the VS 2015 RC is out this has changed again. You will now use `dnx451` / `dnxcore451` as your target frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

In RC2 of asp.net core, use

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
```

and

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies: "1.0.0-rc2-final",
```

Never use `Microsoft.Owin...` in a ASP.NET core - those are for traditional ASP.NET applications.